not sure this is chinese, can anyone tell me what it means? I was told it is a symbol for heaven
can you tell me what this means and what language it is?

How old are you? :)

Judging from the skin tone, and doing a tattoo without knowing the language, he is quite young?, at least at the time the tattoo was done?

It looks like the tattoo was applied as its mirror image too. It is more common than I thought, as to someone who does not know Chinese, they consider some chinesee characters to be symmetrical, but it is rarely the case.

I went from what I saw on the wall at the tattoo shop, got this tattoo long ago before the internet and goggle. I did meet a guy at work a while back who did say that yes it could mean heaven but I never asked the guy what language it was in, now that I google it I see many similar symbols but nothing exactly like what I have, which is why I came on here

It should be "天" - sky; heaven; god. Unfortunately, the tattoo artist made it like "夭" - die young.
 
Note, before getting upset and arguing with the tattoo artist, depending on the word paired with it in a compound word, the word "夭" can also mean - young; be delicate and charming; tender and beautiful. (夭娇; 夭妍; 夭桃; 夭饶; 夭冶)

We need to know the words on top to know what it really is? It looks a lot like  "夭"?

The words above are my cousins name who died and I had the symbol for heaven or what I thought was tattooed below his name

Sorry for your loss. Now it probably make sense as your cousin died "young"?, and so it could be  "夭" , (youthful passing), or "天", (in Heaven)  Perhaps the Tattoo master really knew what he was doing, assuming you explained the sad situation to him?

thank you, I had not thought of that, maybe he did change it to better suit my situation

Maybe give Wayne Cheah an uptick in rewarding his relentless pursuit and uncover this mystery :)

what is an uptick?

Click on the triangle in front of the commenting line, it will turn blue to indicate your acceptance and appreciation of the content.

I did that but it says I need 15 reputation to cast a vote but my feedback was taken. I said thank you in my reply to him, thank you.

You are welcome. I forgot the minimum points requirement.
